# Announcement to display just the title in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How to display just the title in Announcement on the Home page. Can I hide the body so it can be seen only if you click on the title in SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. You want to edit the Announcements web part and change the view. You could modify the existing view to remove the columns you don't want, or open the Announcements list and create a new view that only has the Name (linked to document) then use that for your web part.

[Here's a short guide.](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-display-views-via-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2.html)

Comment: Thank you. This was really easy. This was just out of mind I dont know why. Anyways Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No worries! We all have those moments. Be sure to mark as answer if this answered your question!